# Getting current device language in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nslocale

I'd like to show the current language that the device UI is using. What code would I use?

I want this as an `NSString` in fully spelled out format. (Not @"en_US")

EDIT: For those driving on by, there are a ton of useful comments here, as the answer has evolved with new iOS releases.

Comment: This is built into `NSLocale`. See my answer.

Comment: **iOS9 comment:** pay attention to the fact that for some weird reason, Apple has changed the format returned by `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`. it used to be separated by underscore (e.g. `en_US`), but now it was changed into a dash: `en-US`

Comment: More on iOS9: Getting [NSLocale preferredLanguages] on a iOS 8.4 simulator versus 9.0 simulator also has discrepancies.  On iOS 8.4 it is "en" and iOS 9.0 it is "en-US"

Comment: This comment helped me a lot! We were stuck with a simple issue wondering what went wrong for about 1 hour until I saw your comment.

Comment: `NSLocale` has methods `componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:` and `localeIdentifierFromComponents:` which are probably the right way to handle the (potentially changeable) format.

Answer (score 832, accepted):

The solutions provided will actually return the current region of the device - not the currently selected language. These are often one and the same. However, if I am in North America and I set my language to Japanese, my region will still be English (United States). In order to retrieve the currently selected language, you can do:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
```

This will return a two letter code for the currently selected language. "en" for English, "es" for Spanish, "de" for German, etc. For more examples, please see this Wikipedia entry (in particular, the 639-1 column):

[List of ISO 639-1 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

Then it's a simple matter of converting the two letter codes to the string you would like to display. So if it's "en", display "English".

**EDIT**

Worth to quote the header information from NSLocale.h:

```
+ (NSArray *)preferredLanguages NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0); // note that this list does not indicate what language the app is actually running in; the [NSBundle mainBundle] object determines that at launch and knows that information
```

People interested in app language take a look at [@mindvision's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497352)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had the same issue where region is not the same as language.

Comment: bad answer: returns zh-Hans for chinese, which is not the iso code.

Comment: The first two characters give the country, the stuff after the dash gives the region, the rest is just for narrowing it down further (such as local dialects). zh is listed as the iso code for Chinese. For those looking for a specific language like I was, try the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)

Comment: This is working in the simulator, but when I use this on my iPhone 5 running iOS 6, it always returns "en" even though I've selected Español as my language, for testing. I've also tried also selecting Mexico as my region, that has no effect. Every time I start the app up it reports "en." Any ideas?

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti: I haven't revisited this code since I wrote it back a a couple of years. However, after searching for a few minutes I haven't found any indication that this functionality has changed in iOS6. Without seeing your specific implementation I'm unsure where the issue may be. I hope you were able to track down the source.

Comment: Still looking, sadly. It's totally bizarre because it works fine in the simulator, just not on my actual phone. I'll report back if I figure anything out.

Comment: So strange... my code works fine in simulator AND on an iPhone 4 running iOS 6. But on my iPhone 5, it always sees my language as "en." The language change is reflected everywhere else on the phone, except my app.

Comment: Note: British English is en-GB

Comment: zh-Hans is the only exception or there are other language codes which differ from the ISO 639-1 standard?

Comment: @Elsint this is the approach that fits my use case.

Comment: It seems `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` doesn't work on simulators in Xcode 6.1. I'm having the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572115/nslocale-preferredlanguages-objectatindex0-always-return-en

Comment: Just a warning that it's not just Chinese that's a bit different. My device returns en-GB for British English.  So you do need to parse the output carefully.

Comment: ***Warning: in iOS 9***, the return value of the `NSLocale preferredLanguages` changed. If before you have been getting "en" only, in iOS 9 you will get "en-US" or "en-JP", etc. Reference: https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/nslocale-preferredlanguages-changes-in-ios-9/

Comment: what is solution for iOS 9?

Comment: preferredLanguages amy not return the actual language the phone is set to. See dreamlab's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30293909/555807

Comment: It is not true, because in Apple documentation there is a note about that method: `// note that this list does not indicate what language the app is actually running in; the [NSBundle mainBundle] object determines that at launch and knows that information`

Comment: @MikeRhodes WARNING, PLEASE CHANGE YOUR COMMENT ASAP. This DOES NOT WORK for differentiating Chinese Simplified vs Chinese Traditional.

Comment: @ajnin I'm not sure what to change my comment to -- if you have a suggestion, let me know and I'll update it. As mentioned a couple of times in this thread, and hinted at in my comment, for differentiating certain things you'll need to poke further down the locale string.

Comment: @MikeRhodes The thread has gotten quite long and this SO question has gotten quite popular. Since your comment is highly upvoted, putting a warning that this doesn't work with Chines languages will help everyone out substantially, even if it's already mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Given no one has mentioned this, the returned code is IETF BCP 47 (tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) so can have various parts beyond the initial two. Often just two chars are needed, so the best thing is: [[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:2]. Note that some differentiations require more than the first two characters (e.g., Chinese simplified vs. traditions, English GB vs US).

Comment: How to get the list of supported iOS languages with Country

Comment: You should use `[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]` to reflect the last changes.

Answer (score 292):

The selected answer returns the current device language, but not the actual language used in the app. If you don't provide a localization in your app for the user's preferred language, the first localization available, ordered by the user's preferred order, is used.

To discover the current language selected within your localizations use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];
```

Example:

```
NSString *language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Swift:

```
let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first as NSString
```

Comment: what if we want to get the entire language name after this?

Comment: If you want to get the entire language name from the preferredLocalization, you can use [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:language] (from above). Then you have the locale and can call displayNameForKey.

Comment: Hey it's not working for iOS 14.5, I've set Device Language as Spanish and app is still getting the English language. Don't know why.

Answer (score 92):

**iOS13, Swift 5+**

```
Locale.preferredLanguages.first
```

**Solution for iOS 9:**

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

language = "en-US"

```
NSDictionary *languageDic = [NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:language];
```

languageDic will have the needed components

```
NSString *countryCode = [languageDic objectForKey:@"kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey"];
```

countryCode = "US"

```
NSString *languageCode = [languageDic objectForKey:@"kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey"];
```

languageCode = "en"

Comment: [kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF/blob/master/CFLocaleKeys.c#L47) is a defined constant you can use rather than making your own string.

Comment: NSLocaleLanguageCode = @"kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey"

Comment: use NSLocaleCountryCode and NSLocaleLanguageCode for @"kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey", @"kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey", repectively

Answer (score 67):

This will probably give you what you want:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier 
                                         value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
```

It will show the name of the language, in the language itself.
For example:

```
Français (France)
English (United States)
```

Comment: wrong answer: this returns the locale, not the language, which can be different...

Comment: This is definitely wrong, for example if you set the language in the phone settings to English and the Region format to lets say German, Germany, the example above returns "German". Still the phone language is set to English.

Comment: This is not wrong at all. The locale contains both language and region information. So in @jake_hetfield's example it wouldn't return "German", it would return "English (Germany)". This combined with dreamlab's answer should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 38):

[image: warning] The accepted, and the other answers all don't take into account that the **preferred language can be another language than the device language**.

The **device language** is the language in which operating system elements and Apple apps are presented.

The **preferred language** is the language the user would like to have apps localized in. Apple only provides a limited set of translations. If the preferred language is one language Apple translated their apps to, it will also be the device language. **However** if the user prefers a language for which Apple doesn't provide translations the **device and preferred languages won't match**. The device language will not be on first position in the preferred languages list.

The following function will go through the preferred languages list and check if there is a translation in the Apple frameworks. The first language to have a translation is the device language. The function will return its language code.

```
func deviceLanguage() -> String? {
    let systemBundle: NSBundle = NSBundle(forClass: UIView.self)
    let englishLocale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")

    let preferredLanguages: [String] = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()

    for language: String in preferredLanguages {
        let languageComponents: [String : String] = NSLocale.componentsFromLocaleIdentifier(language)

        guard let languageCode: String = languageComponents[NSLocaleLanguageCode] else {
            continue
        }

        // ex: es_MX.lproj, zh_CN.lproj
        if let countryCode: String = languageComponents[NSLocaleCountryCode] {
            if systemBundle.pathForResource("\(languageCode)_\(countryCode)", ofType: "lproj") != nil {
                // returns language and country code because it appears that the actual language is coded within the country code aswell
                // for example: zh_CN probably mandarin, zh_HK probably cantonese
                return language
            }
        }

        // ex: English.lproj, German.lproj
        if let languageName: String = englishLocale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: languageCode) {
            if systemBundle.pathForResource(languageName, ofType: "lproj") != nil {
                return languageCode
            }
        }

        // ex: pt.lproj, hu.lproj
        if systemBundle.pathForResource(languageCode, ofType: "lproj") != nil {
            return languageCode
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works if the preferred language list is:

1. Afrikaans *(iOS is not translated into Afrikaans)*
2. Spanish *(Device Language)*

The **preferred language list** can be **edited in**: Settings.app -> General -> Language & Region -> Preferred Language Order

---

You can than use the device language code and translate it into the language name. The following lines will print the device language in the device language. For example "Español" if the device is set to spanish.

```
if let deviceLanguageCode: String = deviceLanguage() {
    let printOutputLanguageCode: String = deviceLanguageCode
    let printOutputLocale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: printOutputLanguageCode)

    if let deviceLanguageName: String = printOutputLocale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: deviceLanguageCode) {
        // keep in mind that for some localizations this will print a language and a country
        // see deviceLanguage() implementation above
        print(deviceLanguageName)
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that by initializing your bundle instance with `NSBundle(forClass: UIView.self)` you're trying to provide the most specific language for a given view. However, using this I ran into an issue where for the given class a language was not returned. I changed the initialization to `NSBundle.mainBundle()` and was returned the expected language code.

Comment: Clarification: Initializing the bundle with `mainBundle()` appears to be the one recommended by Apple as suggested in the header for `NSLocale`, `// note that this list does not indicate what language the app is actually running in; the [NSBundle mainBundle] object determines that at launch and knows that information`.

Comment: @Pouria `NSBundle.mainBundle()` returns your app bundle, whereas `NSBundle(forClass: UIView.self)` returns the systems UIKit bundle. the described method looks for directories in the bundle. your app bundle will only contain the ones for the languages you intend to localize to. to determine the device language you will need to check the system bundle.

Comment: @Pouria the issue might have been that iOS 9 changed the return values from `NSLocale.preferredLanguages()`. i **updated the answer to support iOS 9**.

Comment: @dreamlab unfortunately this approach gives false-positive results when you include 3rd party components, such as pods, with localizations you don't support in project settings.

Comment: @kokoko can you please explain why and how? do the pods change the system bundles?

Comment: @dreamlab no, but when I added German for example as one of preferred languages before English in system settings, I launched this test and it fired the last condition, looking for German.lproj in UIKit.framework. My project was not supposed to support german language, there was only english localization.

Comment: @kokoko this is correct. this solution returns the device ui language. not your apps language. see second sentence: _The device language is the language in which operating system elements and Apple apps are presented._

Comment: @dreamlab is there any way to find intersection between supported localizations of app and preferred languages, defined in system settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105159/discussion-between-kokoko-and-dreamlab).

Comment: No we are not getting device system language with this. always getting "English"

Answer (score 18):

**iOS13, Swift 5+, WWDC2019**
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/403/

Users can select the preferred language of an app independently from the OS language.

You can use these:

```
    // Returns a list of the user's preferred languages.
    // Maybe more than (or none of) your app supports!
    Locale.preferredLanguages

    // a subset of this bundle's localizations, re-ordered into the preferred order
    // for this process's current execution environment; the main bundle's preferred localizations
    // indicate the language (of text) the user is most likely seeing in the UI
    Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations



    // The current running app language
    Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first

    // list of language names this bundle appears to be localized to
    Bundle.main.localizations
```

Answer (score 12):

i use this

```
    NSArray *arr = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
for (NSString *lan in arr) {
    NSLog(@"%@: %@ %@",lan, [NSLocale canonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString:lan], [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lan] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:lan]);
}
```

ignore memory leak..

and result is

```
2013-03-02 20:01:57.457 xx[12334:907] zh-Hans: zh-Hans 中文（简体中文）
2013-03-02 20:01:57.460 xx[12334:907] en: en English
2013-03-02 20:01:57.462 xx[12334:907] ja: ja 日本語
2013-03-02 20:01:57.465 xx[12334:907] fr: fr français
2013-03-02 20:01:57.468 xx[12334:907] de: de Deutsch
2013-03-02 20:01:57.472 xx[12334:907] nl: nl Nederlands
2013-03-02 20:01:57.477 xx[12334:907] it: it italiano
2013-03-02 20:01:57.481 xx[12334:907] es: es español
```

Comment: just for curiosity, where is the memory leak here?

Comment: Leak - [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lan].

Comment: Only for non-ARC projects, though.

Answer (score 12):

Translating language codes such as **en_US** into **English (United States)** is a built in feature of `NSLocale` and `NSLocale` does not care where you get the language codes from. So there really is no reason to implement your own translation as the accepted answer suggests.

```
// Example code - try changing the language codes and see what happens
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
NSString *l1 = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"en"];
NSString *l2 = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"de"];
NSString *l3 = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"sv"];
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", l1, l2, l3);
```

Prints: **English, German, Swedish**

Comment: Actually, you should use [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale] to initialize your locale instance. That way the language names will be displayed in the users native language. For example Swedish will become Svenska.

Answer (score 8):

Even there's a better way to get current device language. Let's try it by below code -

```
NSLog(@"Current Language - %@", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject]);
```

Suggested by [Abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern) on [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12529944#12529944)

Answer (score 8):

I tried to found out the right solution for myself. When I use `Locale.preferredLanguages.first` was returned the preferred language from your app settings.

If you want get to know language from user device settings, you should the use string below:

**Swift 3**

```
let currentDeviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
// Will return the optional String
```

To unwrap and use look at the line below:

```
if let currentDeviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode {
    print("currentLanguage", currentDeviceLanguage)

    // For example
    if currentDeviceLanguage == "he" {
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    } else {
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }
}
```

Comment: you don;t have to unwrap if you use this Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0] as String

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `displayNameForKey:value:` method of [`NSLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
// get a French locale instance
NSLocale *frLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];

// use it to get translated display names of fr_FR and en_US
NSLog(@"%@", [frLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"fr_FR"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [frLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"en_US"]);
```

This will print out:

```
français (France)
anglais (États-Unis)
```

If you specify the same locale identifier for the `initWithLocaleIdentifier:` and also the `displayNameForKey:value:` method, then it will give you the native name of the language. I've discovered that if you remove the country code and use just `fr` and `en`, that it will also omit the country from the display name (on Mac OS X at least, not sure about iOS).

Answer (score 6):

### *Swift*

*To get current language of device*

```
NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String
```

*To get application language*

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations[0] as NSString
```

*Note:*

It fetches the language that you have given in *CFBundleDevelopmentRegion* of info.plist

if *CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations* is true in info.plist then first item of *CFBundleLocalizations* in info.plist is returned

Answer (score 5):

For getting user device current language use the following it code it worked for me.

```
NSString * myString = [[NSLocale preferredlanguage]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for preferred language code ("en", "de", "es" ...), and localized preferred language name (for current locale), here's a simple extension in Swift:

```
extension Locale {
    static var preferredLanguageIdentifier: String {
        let id = Locale.preferredLanguages.first!
        let comps = Locale.components(fromIdentifier: id)
        return comps.values.first!
    }

    static var preferredLanguageLocalizedString: String {
        let id = Locale.preferredLanguages.first!
        return Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: id)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For MonoTouch C# developers use:

```
NSLocale.PreferredLanguages.FirstOrDefault() ?? "en"
```

Note: I know this was an iOS question, but as I am a MonoTouch developer, the answer on this page led me in the right direction and I thought I'd share the results.

Comment: I'm currently using NSLocale.PreferredLanguages and I'm getting an empty array. I assume you've read in the documentation that it may never be empty but I can't see this anywhere?

Comment: No, honestly that was just an assumption of my own.

Comment: @LarryF Watch this video: http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/cross-platform-mobile-ndc-2011/  It is very informative on how to structure your code / multi-platform apps.

Answer (score 3):

In `Swift`:

```
let languageCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as? String
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
let locale = Locale.current
let code = (locale as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode) as! String?
print(code!)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Swift 3 function:

```
@discardableResult
func getLanguageISO() -> String {
    let locale = Locale.current
    guard let languageCode = locale.languageCode,
          let regionCode = locale.regionCode else {
        return "de_DE"
    }
    return languageCode + "_" + regionCode
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *)returnPreferredLanguage { //as written text

NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *preferredLanguages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *preferredLanguageCode = [preferredLanguages objectAtIndex:0]; //preferred device language code
NSLocale *enLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"]; //language name will be in English (or whatever)
NSString *languageName = [enLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:preferredLanguageCode]; //name of language, eg. "French"
return languageName;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only language here is my suggested answer:

```
NSString *langplusreg = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * langonly = [[langplusreg componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] 
objectAtIndex:0];
```

In my case i just wanted only Locale language not locale region.

Output:
If your Locale language is Japanese and locale region is Japan then:

langplusreg = ja-JP

langonly = ja

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the solutions relying, for example, on

```
[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]
```

usually work fine and return the current device language.

**But it could be misleading in some cases :**

If the app in which you want to get this value has already changed the language, for example with this kind of code :

```
NSString *lg = @"en"; // or anything like @"en", @"fr", etc.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:lg, nil]  
    forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]
```

In this case, [NSLocale preferredLanguages] **actually returns the preferred language set (and used) in this particular app, not the current device language !**

And... in this case the only way to properly get the actual current device language (and not that previously set in the app), is to firstly clear the key @"appleLanguages" in NSUserDefaults, like this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Then, [NSLocale preferredLanguages] now returns the correct value.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

```
let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
debugPrint(language)//en
```

In Swift 5.x

```
let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode
debugPrint(langStr ?? "") //en  el
```

Answer (score 1):

@amir response in Swift :

```
// Get language prefered by user
let langageRegion = NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first!
let languageDic = NSLocale.componentsFromLocaleIdentifier(langageRegion)
let language = languageDic[NSLocaleLanguageCode]
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT-4

```
 // To get device default selected language. It will print like short name of zone. For english, en or spain, es.

let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first! as NSString
print("device language",language)
```

Comment: Note that this fetches the aggregated list of *available* (supported by the bundle ie you) and *preferred* (by the user) localizations.  `NSLocale.preferredLanguages` should return the user's preferred ones without paying respect to what is supported by the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I actually misread the original question, thought it asked for the "app UI" language (that's what I had googled for), not the "device UI", in which case the best answers would be the ones using `preferredLocalizations`, but those answers still give you a code, there is one more step to get a nice string to display.
So, while the "device UI" language is already answered, if you want to display a nice string for which of the UI languages you support is currently in use, obviously the simplest solution is:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"currentLanguage", @"")
```

Where in every one of your UI localizations you have specified it exactly the way you want it shown. E.g. in the `en` version of your `.strings` file you'd have:

```
"currentLanguage"="English";
```

in your `fr` version of the `.strings` file you'd have:

```
"currentLanguage"="Francais";
```

etc. No messing with codes etc, you make your own strings to nicely match your UI.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html)

```
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString* preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two letters format. Apple uses the [ISO standard ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

```
NSString *localeCountryCode = [[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0] as String

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 9, if you just want the language code without country code, you'll want this sort of helper function - since the language will contain the country code.

```
// gets the language code without country code in uppercase format, i.e. EN or DE
NSString* GetLanguageCode()
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSString* lang;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        lang = [[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] uppercaseString];
        NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[A-Za-z]+" options:0 error:nil];
        NSTextCheckingResult* match = [regex firstMatchInString:lang options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, lang.length)];
        if (match.range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            lang = [lang substringToIndex:match.range.length];
        }
    });
    return lang;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer for Swift 4**

```
let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first
```

Comment: Note that this fetches the aggregated list of *available* (supported by the bundle ie you) and *preferred* (by the user) localizations.  `NSLocale.preferredLanguages` should return the user's preferred ones without paying respect to what is supported by the bundle.

Comment: I can vouch that the above code works for Swift 5. You would have to do guard or let to quite the warning or preferredLanguages[0].

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0 below code can be used to answer your question:

```
 let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first! as NSString
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.x** 
Device Language we can get it using
`Locale.current.languageCode` but it would return 
`en` for english, 
`zh` for Chinese-simplified , and 
`zh` for Chinese - traditional

Actually it would more helpful when we will get something like.

`zh-Hans` for Chinese-simplified , and

`zh-Hant` for Chinese - traditional

Here `zh` is language code and `Hans` is scriptCode.

**Solution:**

```html
extension Locale {
    
    static var preferredLanguageNScripCodes: [String] {
        Locale.preferredLanguages.compactMap {
            if let scriptCode = Locale(identifier: $0).scriptCode,
               let languageCode = Locale(identifier: $0).languageCode {
                return languageCode + "-" + scriptCode
            }
            return Locale(identifier: $0).languageCode
        }
    }
}
```

For example: `["zh-Hant", "en", "zh-Hans", "ko", "ja", "es", "de", "it", "fr", "en"]`

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift**, there is a way **simpler answer** to get the current app language:

```swift
Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]).languageCode!
```

It could be switched over like this for example:

```swift
let supportUrl: URL = {
    switch Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]).languageCode {
    case "de":
        return Constants.supportUrlGerman

    default:
        return Constants.supportUrlEnglish
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!