# How to use the keyboard with custome language in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Now I want to use a custome keyboard in iPhone, just like when a keyboard show, it will show a japanese keyboard , How to do , thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change iOS device keyboard to specific language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073254/how-to-change-ios-device-keyboard-to-specific-language)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you change it system-wide (or build a custom keyboard using inputAccesoryView), it's not currently possible, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073254/how-to-change-ios-device-keyboard-to-specific-language)

Comment: thank you very much, I have searched , but no result. So I think maybe use custome keyboard.