# How do I make my iOS app show an Eastern Arabic decimal pad when I tap a UITextView?

Tags: ios, localization, arabic, iphone-keypad

I have a UITextView that I created on a XIB with IB. I set the "Keyboard" property to "Decimal Pad", but no matter how I change my iOS preferences it never shows a keypad with [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) (٠‎ ١‎ ٢‎ ٣‎ ٤‎ ٥‎ ٦‎ ٧‎ ٨‎ ٩‎).

How do I set my iPhone preferences or what do I need to do in IB or my code to get the iPhone to show an Arabic keypad when the user has set an Arabic locale?

Comment: This has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073254/how-to-change-ios-device-keyboard-to-specific-language) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language) is a similar question. So pm444's answer seems legit, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Similar, but not the same. I'm asking about the keyPAD (like the one that comes up in the phone app) not the keyBOARD (which is controlled by the user's preferences.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add a new keyboard language.
Go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard and select the required keyboard.
If you want Arabic first priority then click on to Edit button and change the priority by dragging it. This will enable the Arabic keypad open at first.