# Custom Localization solution - How to submit such an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization, app-store-connect

We have an app which is in English and Spanish.

In our app, user can change the language within the app. User doesn't have to change the language of the device to change the app language.

In such a scenario, we did not use localization instead directly translated the language.

We already have this app in Enlish in App Store. Is there a way we can submit the app keeping Spanish lanaguage as default?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application into the App Store you should provide a good user experience.

From the localization point of view this means:

- By default use OS language, if OS language does not match your language list pick English
- Optionally, allow user to change the language and remember it
- configuration should be implemented the iOS way, so you can access the setting from inside de Settings menu.

Comment: So what do you suggest I should do in my current scenario? The app is such that it makes sense to change the language from within the app. So we did not implemented localization based on that.

Comment: Rewrite, it's never too late to repair mistakes and also it is very simple to get the list of OS languages and make decisions based on that.

Comment: You mean include localizations in the app?

Comment: Even if you used your own localization solution, you can always check the [current iOS device language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios) and use it, instead of asking the user.

Comment: WTH?! "user can choose" where? If you build the application twice, you have two applications and in this case you have to implement localization for it. Doing separate builds is a no go. If this is true, you made a really bad mistake for year 2011. Also, there is not way to explain how localization works on a single SO question but I assure you it's not hard to do it, it is much harder to do it wrongly.

Comment: No, its not two seperate builds. Its the same app, but there is a toggle button in Settings section by which user can change the language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5716/discussion-between-sorin-and-meetpd)