# How to check the iPhone language settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm localizing my app which is cocos2d so there are no nib files, I'm localizing a label which is fine but want to check the device language to set an exact font and font size for each language. In short I want to do it as the following:

```
If (device.language == en) {
Set font to "fontname" and "fontsize" to x;
} else {
set it to "another font name" and font size to y;
}
```

How to check that the device language/settings is set to an exact language?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]
```

This will return a language tag like “en” or “ja”.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted

Comment: This is not true, in Apple documentation there is a note about that method: `// note that this list does not indicate what language the app is actually running in; the [NSBundle mainBundle] object determines that at launch and knows that information`