# Is there a delegate call when iOS keyboard language changes?

Tags: ios, ios5, keyboard

I have a scenario where I'd like to have a handler that gets triggered when the user presses the language change(globe icon) on the keyboard for iOS.

How I may achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:
You would have to use a UIKeyboard notification within your code

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then within your `keyboardWillBeHidden:` or similarly named method use the answer (link below) which returns you a two letter code for the currently selected language.

Link: [Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios/)

So your method `keyboardWillBeHidden:` method is called when the keyboard is hidden reads from the system the keyboard language option that is currently selected.

Thats the theory, I haven't tried this myself, good luck.

Comment: `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is not triggered when the user changes the language through the globe icon. So I don't understand why this answer is accepted.

Comment: So true @nschum