# keyboard language in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

Are there  Notifications or Delegate functions that detect switching keyboard language?

When I press Language Key in keyboard .. I need a delegate function that handle this in the code to change the direction of UITextfield.

Comment: Check the below Link:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801587/is-there-a-delegate-call-when-ios-keyboard-language-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101543/notification-for-change-of-ipad-keyboard-height):

> The answer is that when you switch languages, the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification fires for each change

So you'll just have to register for that notification and then run your code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSString * currentLanguage = [UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage;
}
```

**Update**

The above method doesn't work, however if we register to `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` we do get a callback.

Comment: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is firing only  when the uikeyboard will show but if i press languages key to change the language of the keyboard  it is not firing anything  :(

Comment: @ZiadBouIsmail You are correct. I guess it worked before and doesn't anymore. Please see my update.