# ios internationalization font assign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts, internationalization

I'm working on a internationalization app, and the problem is:

If using english environment then I can set font like "Helvetica"

If using Chinese environment then I can set Chinese font.

Is there a way auto switch font depends on which language env is?

For example:

I prepare two fonts: en_font and cn_font, judge iOS language env, if language is english then use en_font otherwise cn_font

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

```
[UITextInputMode currentInputMode]. primaryLanguage
```

Comment: Sorry mate, [UITextInputMode currentInputMode]. primaryLanguage result will change if input keyboard change. I need a way to find out which language the iOS OS is using. Not keyboard type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios this is the answer, thanks buddy!