# MonoTouch: CurrentCulture when "Language" set

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, currentculture

On an iPhone, when the user sets their **Language** to **French** and their **Region Format** to **United States**, the CurrentCulture represents **en-US**.

Only when the user sets their **Region Format** to France do I get **fr-FR**;

How can I determine the language if the user has set their **Langauge**, but not their **Region Format**?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at `NSLocale`, e.g. `NSLocale.CurrentLocale.Identifier` to get a string like `en-US`. That will give you the *exact* values that iOS is using.

Both .NET and iOS have similar, but subtly different, API to get those values. It's difficult to be fully compatible with .NET by using only iOS data (it's not a perfect fit). In some case, e.g. `RegionInfo`, we have been able to *bootstrap* the .NET classes using iOS provided data. As more features becomes available we might be able to do the same for other types in the future.

Comment: I use your solution, but It keeps getting me "en_US", even when I have set the language to Spanish, but the regional format to United States, how do I get the language?, I´m using xamarin.

Comment: THis gives me the 3 letter language code fairly well I have since found. Set the Region Format in the Settings app to Korean to get "KOR" for example: iSOLanguage = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName.ToUpper ()

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocale.CurrentLocale` gives the region format, not the language.

To get the language, use `NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0]` instead. The result will be a string like `fr` or `en-US` for the language that is selected.

For more info, see [Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios).