# How to identify the user's language in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode-string, nslocale

I'm very new to iOS and Objective-C and I've been working on a project for an SMS app in which the app contains a text box for the message and that box has a counter for the characters but the counter depends on the language of the text, so my question is how can I identify/detect what language is the user using?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to only use the Xcode tag for questions about Xcode the IDE, not iOS the platform. I believe you'll fine the answer in the question I nominated as a duplicate. If not please edit your question and indicate what about those answers didn't answer your question. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you and I didn't find these questions before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get user's prefered language list by using `NSLocal`:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([language isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    NSLog(@"user's prefered first language is English");
}
```

Comment: thank you this helped in a part but I don't know why it always returns english only even when I use the other language. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

Have a look at this: [Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios)

Comment: have a look at this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial