# Get language and country code (ISO 639-1)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cultureinfo

Is there a solution for xamarin-ios to get the current culture in the format like (en_US, de_CH, ..)? I read so many articles in the web and here on stackoverflow. But I can't find a nice solution for this.

Following code snippet returns not this format everytime. Sometimes I get "gsw_DE" and so on (ISO 639-2 instead of 639-1)

```
NSLocale.CurrentLocale.Identifier;
```

My current solution is to do it by myself:

```
var languagecode = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];

var result = String.Format("{0}_{1}", languagecode.Substring(0, 2), NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode);
```

Above workaround is from: [Get iOS current language (including country code)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18699441/2653134)

I need to make sure that I get the value in this format.
Is there another way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are still in the C# world, aren't we?
You can use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` and it'll give you "en-US" for "default" English and "en-GB" for English UK. Language settings are in General - Language & Region - iPhone Language.

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried at first. But on one of our iOS devices, the value is everytime not set (empty string). Even if I change the language on the phone.

Some web searchs result in the key, that this is the wrong way to get the current culture/language for ios.

Comment: Do you have issues with some particular languages? As I've tested CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture on my phone and it works just fine. Which Xamarin version are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is the language itselfs. The phone supports swiss-german-language. And this is not an ISO 639-1 standard. In case of this, the CultureInfo.CUrrentUICulture is not set. The other iPhon-devices which are not swiss-german worked.