# How can I detect the system language of an iOS device using JavaScript?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios) but it uses C. Is there a way to do this through JQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: You mentioned JavaScript, can I assume your codes will be loaded in `UIWebView` ?

Comment: This is for browsers, will it work the same on an iOS iPad app?

Comment: I am using Cordova @Shivan, so I haven't used or changed any Objective C code.

Comment: Then it's not related to other tags. Retag as Cordova / PhoneGap .

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. Thanks for the link I will have a read now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE:
This plugin is not required any more, and its no longer included in default installations.
The current way of obtaining it is `navigator.language`
See https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language

---

Below method will help you to find your device language using Cordova/Phonegap.

```
function checkLanguage() {
    navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
        function (language) {    
            alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');
        },
        function () {
            alert('Error getting language\n');
        }
    );
}
```

Note: Check the [Cordova Globalization plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) for more.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage` vs `navigator.language` ?

Comment: Now in 2018, use `navigator.language`. There is a deprecation notice on the readme of the cordova plugin.