# How to detect system language in Cordova using Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

How to detect system language in Cordova using Java script,I need to detect the language for Android and iOS app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect the system language of an iOS device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490975/how-can-i-detect-the-system-language-of-an-ios-device-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`navigator.language` seems like the simplest way for you to do this

```js
let language = navigator.language

console.log(language);
```