# iPad detection keyboard / language

Tags: ipad, localization, keyboard

I do have three separate questions but they all linked together.

Is it possible to detect if the user changes keyboard language?

Is it possible to detect what language the keyboard is currently set to.

Is it possible to detect what language the iPad is set to?

Thanks

Comment: Detect device lang: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `NSLocale` and `autoupdatingCurrentLocale` to determine the current locale and have it automatically update if the user changes settings.

`NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` will tell you when the locale changes.