# How to detect correctly language user of device objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I have a query about iOS. I want to detect language of my device, for change any texts in my app if language is english and other if isn't english. But when I detect language, always detect region and not detect language. In others words if I go to change language, this don't change. If I change region, language changes.

My code is:

```
 NSString *userLocale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
NSString *userLanguage = [userLocale substringToIndex:2];
NSLog(@"%@", userLanguage); // return format "en", "es"... (english or spanish)
```

Could be that this problem appear because with [NSLocale currentLocale] get en_Us and this parameters depends of region?

Thanks!

Comment: This link might also help. Nice link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the language try

```
[NSLocale preferredLanguages];
```

It will return an array of the user's language preference and the most preferred language will be the first in the list.

NSLocale encapsulates a lot more than just the current language.  Things like currency identifier and what to use for the decimal separator are just a few.  A Spanish speaking user in the northwestern United States may want to see things in Spanish but would probably still expect to see the $ for currency.

With that said I suspect what your really looking for is full fledged localization support in which case there is tons of information out there on how to localize your app.  The macro

```
NSLocalizedString
```

and its siblings allow you to write language agnostic code (for the most part).

Comment: NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]; but I am getting "en" always. Could be that in simulator the language always is english? Tomorrow I can try in a device for see this.

Comment: Yes.  Change the devices language to something else and it will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode() 
// return format "en-GB", "en-AU", "zh-CN"
```