# Convert country code to name in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I have some two-letter country codes that I want to covert them into a country name with localised language, like
US -> United States if the user is using English
HK -> 香港 if the user is using Chinese
etc
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios) to get the system region. You can put the system languages in a [dictionary](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary) to determine the country.

A caveat -- this method, as mentioned in the answer, returns the region, not necessarily the system language. Most of the time, they'll be the same, but if a user is multilingual, it might just take his region instead of all languages.