# I got this when I use Xcode 7? any ideas?

Tags: ios, xcode7

Got following error:

```
 no visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'primaryLanguage'
```

at following code:

````
 NSString *lang = [[[UITextInputMode activeInputModes] firstObject] primaryLanguage];
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```NSString *lang = [[[UITextInputMode activeInputModes] firstObject] primaryLanguage];```
````

[image]

Comment: Yup your not allowed use it. You should use NSString * language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];  to get the users primary language for your app. see more at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIKeyboardInputMode` is a private class.

Therefore, you are not allowed to call this method/property. You would have to [add the private header](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKeyboardInputMode.h), which makes it impossible to publish the code in the AppStore.