# What is the list of supported languages/locales on iOS like Android?

Tags: android, ios, locale

I'd like to know what is the language code for Specific language in iOS.
because there is conflicts to get same language code for Android & iOS which I want use in my Web service data.
Below is the example list for Android.

Is it same or different?
Can anyone help to get iOS list.
I am an Android developer so don't know how to get it.Please help

```
Language / Locale                 Supported since version
English, US (en_US)               1.1
German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3910244/1168654 & https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) and this [article](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html) it looks like iOS supports all ISO-639 languages codes.

Comment: Ok.
Android supported by ISO 639-1 that's why it gives different codes.
Is it possible to get the same ISO format language code?

Comment: You can use ISO-639-1 or ISO-639-2 codes in iOS. Doesn't matter.

Comment: How it's possible ?
Do you have any example or reference link?

Comment: Look at pages I've linked.