# NSLocale preferredLanguages is retrieving always 'en' language

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get the correct language in my device (is NOT in the SIMULATOR) with the following code:

```
 NSString * languageLocale = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And it is always **'en'**  but my current language is set to **Spanish**

Any thoughts why is retrieving always 'en' and not the current device language?

Comment: Aren't the *preferred* language and the *device* language different things?

Comment: According to this question no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios

Comment: Why are you fetching the language identifier from NSLocale? What do you need it for?

Comment: To identify the language of the device and set it in the User settings, in my app the language can be change it but the first language, the on is selected by default, is the one from the device, so the one from NSLocale.

Comment: This is a very confusing user experience. You should not have an in-app language switcher; users expect all their apps to follow the language chosen in Settings.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I will follow this approach. Thank you!

Comment: I am still facing a problem while trying to do this, I've change my device into english but my app is not recognizing the language. Is still saying that is in 'en'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few research, I found out that the key AppleLanguages was being overwritten.
So, the

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

It was returning a dictionary list with the overwritten data.
I just did this:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * dict = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {
    if([key isEqualToString:@"AppleLanguages"]){
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
[defaults synchronize];
```

In order to delete the whole key and the system reset it and return the correct list.

Comment: Something in your app is overwriting that key, which should probably be removed.

Comment: Yes, I found out where, but the thing is the app is already in the AppStore and the variable was already overwritten so I manage to do this in order to keep the app working as it should be working.

Comment: @wakachamo who overrides the value? and why? my app has no such statement to override it.

Comment: hi @SazzadHissainKhan it's been a while since this question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ZetaPR I am facing the similar issue. Nothing works cz value for key AppleLanguages are being overwritten. I need to know why its being overwritten?

Comment: Well in case of this applications was a legacy one, someone decided that in the main part of the application the Apple Languages keys were overwritten in toder to let decide the user inside the app whether to change or not the language. Despite that guidelines are clear to not do this, the key was already overwritten I had to check the dict to reset this by removing first the code in my main that do the AppleLanguage selection and override and then doing this in order to reset the dictionary back to normal

Answer (score 5):

I've to face the same issue. In my case, it was solved by setting the Application Language as System Language in Edit Scheme.

Here is the way:

Edit Scheme -> Options -> Application language -> System Language.