# Wrong language code swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I set the language of the simulator to French. To check the language code, I used a couple of solutions:

```
let lang = NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrent.languageCode
print(lang)

let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
print(pre)
```

The result are:

```
Optional("en")
fr-US
```

What I expected to get is:

```
fr
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: your problem is that you're getting fr_US instead of fr?

Comment: is there anyway to get just `fr`

Comment: you can take the substring before the _ or if there is no _ take the entire string

Comment: did you got this simulator ?

Comment: your code already fine .

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475770/3901620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try below code,**

```
let requiredString = pre.components(separatedBy: "-").first ?? pre //fr
/*if pre.contains("-"), then requiredString = before("-") else requiredString = pre*/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(Locale.components(fromIdentifier: Locale.preferredLanguages[0])["kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey"]!)
```

this will print language code only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Language instead of the Language_Region, then I suggest to take the sub string before the _ from the string to neglect the Region.

(If the string contains no _ then take the entire string since it doesn't contain the region in it)