# NSLocale is not returning correct Language code

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I'm trying to get device current selected language code by using the code below.

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This line works fine for the first time after installation. When I change the device language from device setting, then I'm trying to retrieve device language that time **NSLocale** returns previously selected language.

Help to resolve this.

Comment: KP26 i try above code i am not facing that issue first time i use language as english and second time hindi and run again i get hi-US of hindi langauge.

Comment: check on this answer Link - [StackOverflow for current language device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios)

Comment: @HardikThakkar : Have you uninstalled the app after first time validation and then reinstalled again for Hindi validation?

Comment: No i just change language from setting and run application again.

Answer (score 1):

You should get it with

```
let currentDeviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
```

or Objective-C

```
NSString *languageCode = [NSLocale currentLocale].languageCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by this line

```
NSString *identifier = [[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale ] localeIdentifier];
```

Swift :

```
let identifier = NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrent.localeIdentifier
```