# Translate language code with Xcode 6.1 using NSLocale

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslocale, xcode6.1

Since the last update, I can't translate the language code (en, fr, etc...) into their respective names (English, French, etc...).

It works on a real device, but not in the emulator. It was working using former versions of Xcode. I'm aware that it's written in the release notes that `[NSLocale currentLocale]` may return `en_US` in some situations, but that doesn't explain why they are no more "translated". I use this code:

```
NSString* lang = @"en";
NSLog(@"%@",
    [[NSLocale currentLocale]
        displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
        value:lang]
);
```

which displays `(null)`, instead of `English`.

The problem is that my app is crashing at some places because of that so I would like to know if there's a workaround.

The weird thing is that the following example, given by Apple, works really well.

```
NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
NSString *displayNameString = [frLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"fr_FR"];
NSLog(@"displayNameString fr_FR: %@", displayNameString);
displayNameString = [frLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"en_US"];
NSLog(@"displayNameString en_US: %@", displayNameString);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSLocale currentLocale always returns "en\_US" not user's current language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522210/nslocale-currentlocale-always-returns-en-us-not-users-current-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Xcode release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW1)

> In some situations, [NSLocale currentLocale] may return en_US instead
>   of the chosen locale in the iOS 8.1 simulator. (18512161)

```
+ (NSLocale *)autoupdatingCurrentLocale NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0); // generally you should use this method

+ (NSLocale *)currentLocale;    // an object representing the user's current locale
```

A workaround is to use the first one. Using objectForKey on currentLocal instance works.

```
NSString* lang = @"en_US";
NSLocale *currentLocal = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
//get the localeIdentifier and create a new NSLocale.
id localIdentifier = [currentLocal objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
NSLocale *theLocal = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:localIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%@",[theLocal displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                                                  value:lang]
      );
```

Comment: Hum, it seems to me that what you're doing is just like the code at the end of my question, but I accept it because it resolves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Apple issue for iOS 8.1 *simulator* only - not reproducible on 8.1 devices. See below issue description from Xcode 6.1 release notes:

> Localization and Keyboard settings (including 3rd party keyboards) are
>   not correctly honored by Safari, Maps, and developer apps in the iOS
>   8.1 Simulator. **[NSLocale currentLocale] returns en_US** and only the English and Emoji keyboards are available. (18418630, 18512161).

See [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW1.) for more details.