# How to allow QA to test a device for other regions?

Tags: testing, nslocale

I just had a bug occur where people werent able to use my device in one country. Is there any way for me to setup the test apps i send to QA in order to allow them to test the locale of another country?

Comment: Can you give us more information?

Comment: The platform is in iOS. So they want to be able to test out how the app will function say in china but they are actually in the united states is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an iOS app or Android. If you are talking about iOS app, try testflight to deliver test app to your QA in other region, and if Android, then make a beta release. It will allow them access your app on their device in their region.

Comment: Yes an iPhone app. I know i can send it to another region but we dont wanna do that. They want to be able to test any region from america. Is that possible? I was able to change the region and language setting it in the schema but they want QA to be able to do it also

Comment: I believe resetting the device with correct region and locale will certainly help here prior testing the app for any specific region.

Comment: NO i dont think thats possible since im using [NSLocale currentLocale] it gets the locale from the region they are in.

Comment: May be, but as per my experience device locale is used for testing purpose, but am not sure if it requires implementation change from code point of view or not.
Here is a discussion similar to your problem, it may help too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522210/nslocale-currentlocale-always-returns-en-us-not-users-current-language