# Weird errors when using a 3G connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, nslocale

I'm making a web browser and when I'm connected to a Wi-Fi network everything works fine. When I'm using a 3G connection just from a short 10 minutes of debugging session with his iPhone I found two errors:

The code below throws an exception:

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] languageCode]
```

*The  WKWebView doesn't load anything.*

There kind of errors occur:

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, posting an answer. I find using `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` with recent iOS versions to be more stable. You can read more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535748/3729825). I hope it brings you slightly closer to a solution.